# Replace a string in Column C based on matching index in Column A

Tags: vba, excel

I would appreciate any help on this matter.  I am trying to create an Excel 2010 macro in VBA that will read strings in one spreadsheet row by row, and then search another spreadsheet to see if the value exists in a column of strings.

If/When it finds a matching string in column A, I would like to compare the string in column C of the original spreadsheet with the string in Column C of the spreadsheet being searched.  If both strings are the same, I would like to move on back to the column A search and continue.

If the strings are different I would like to overwrite the string in Column C of the spreadsheet being searched.  I would also like to highlight this change on the searched spreadsheet.

If no matching string is found in column A of the search spreadsheet, then I want to copy the row of the original spreadsheet into the searched spreadsheet and highlight it.

Here's what I have so far, but I can't seem to get it to work properly:

```
Sub SearchRows()
Dim bottomA1 As Integer
bottomA1 = Sheets("Original Spreadsheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim bottomA2 As Integer
bottomA2 = Sheets("Searched Spreadsheet").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
Dim rng1 As Range
Dim rng2 As Range
Dim x As Long
Dim y As Long
Dim foundColumnA As Range
Dim foundColumnC As Range
For Each rng1 In Sheets("Original Spreadsheet").Range("A2:A" & bottomA1)
    With Sheets("Searched Spreadsheet").Range("A2:A" & bottomA2)
        Set foundColumnA = .Find(what:=rng1, _
        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
        LookIn:=xlValues, _
        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
        MatchCase:=False)
            For Each rng2 In Sheets("Original Spreadsheet").Range("E2:E" & bottomA1)
                With Sheets("Searched Spreadsheet").Range("E2:E" & bottomA2)
                        Set foundSize = .Find(what:=rng2, _
                        After:=.Cells(.Cells.Count), _
                        LookIn:=xlValues, _
                        LookAt:=xlWhole, _
                        SearchOrder:=xlByRows, _
                        SearchDirection:=xlNext, _
                        MatchCase:=True)
                If foundColumnC Is Nothing Then
                        bottomE2 = Sheets("Column C Changes").Range("E" &     Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
                        y = bottomA2 + 1
                        rng2.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Column C Changes").Cells(y, "A")
                        Sheets("Column C Changes").Cells    (y, "A").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
                End If
            End With
        Next rng2
    If foundTag Is Nothing Then
        bottomA2 = Sheets("Column A Changes").Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        x = bottomA2 + 1
        rng1.EntireRow.Copy Sheets("Column A Changes").Cells(x, "A")
        Sheets("Column A Changes").Cells(x, "A").EntireRow.Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End If
End With
Next rng1
End Sub
```

Comment: A couple of things: Your code is not clean. Readability is a major factor in coding. It's best if you qualified everything properly and shortened your code so that's actually readable. This way, you can identify the error. Logically, you understand the process, but there are better ways to go about it. A boolean check can be a nice touch, since it's not messy to set-up and very short. Also, it helps writing the logic as a list or as a flow and structuring your code to follow that flow. See my answer below. The set-up is tedious and boring, but the action part is amazingly simple. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You actually have too much code, but they're not set up cleanly. Qualify a lot of things as much as possible so it's cleaner, and try to be consistent with your style. This way you can identify the error as much as possible.

Anyway, on to the code. The basic logic you want is as follows, based on the details above:

1. Check if a string in `Sheet1!A` is in `Sheet2!A`.
2. If found, compare `Column C` values.

   - If `Column C` values are different, set value of `Sheet2` to that in `Sheet1` and highlight.
   - Else, exit.
3. If not found, copy whole row to `Sheet2` and highlight.

Now that we have that written down, it's simpler! :)

Please check my screenshots for my set-up:

**SCREENSHOTS:**

**Sheet1:**

[image]

**Sheet2:**

[image]

Note that for `Sheet2`, I don't have `BK207` onwards. ;) Now, onto the code.

**CODE:**

```
Sub LoopMatchReplace()

    Dim ShSrc As Worksheet, ShTar As Worksheet
    Dim SrcLRow As Long, TarLRow As Long, NextEmptyRow As Long
    Dim RefList As Range, TarList As Range, RefCell As Range, RefColC
    Dim TarCell As Range, TarColC As Range
    Dim IsFound As Boolean
    Dim ToFind As String

    With ThisWorkbook
        Set ShSrc = .Sheets("Sheet1")
        Set ShTar = .Sheets("Sheet2")
    End With

    'Get the last rows for each sheet.
    SrcLRow = ShSrc.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    TarLRow = ShTar.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    'Set the lists to compare.
    Set RefList = ShSrc.Range("A2:A" & SrcLRow)
    Set TarList = ShTar.Range("A2:A" & TarLRow)

    'Initialize boolean, just for kicks.
    IsFound = False

    'Speed up the process.
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False

    'Create the loop.
    For Each RefCell In RefList

        ToFind = RefCell.Value

        'Look for the value in our target column.
        On Error Resume Next
        Set TarCell = TarList.Find(ToFind)
        If Not TarCell Is Nothing Then IsFound = True
        On Error GoTo 0

        'If value exists in target column...
        If IsFound Then
            'Compare the Column C of both sheets.
            Set TarColC = TarCell.Offset(0, 2)
            Set RefColC = RefCell.Offset(0, 2)
            'If they are different, set the value to match and highlight.
            If TarColC.Value <> RefColC.Value Then
                TarColC.Value = RefColC.Value
                TarColC.Interior.ColorIndex = 4
            End If
        Else 'If value does not exist...
            'Get next empty row, copy the whole row from source sheet, and highlight.
            NextEmptyRow = ShTar.Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row + 1
            RefCell.EntireRow.Copy ShTar.Rows(NextEmptyRow)
            ShTar.Rows(NextEmptyRow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
        End If

        'Set boolean check to False.
        IsFound = False

    Next RefCell

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Kindly read the comments for the codeblocks so you get an understanding of what I'm doing. Also, note the way that I have qualified everything and properly set them up in a very clean way. Clean code is 50% good code.

Check the following screenshot to see the results after running the code.

**END RESULT:**

[image]

Note the added rows at the end and the changed values in Column C. I did not have the whole row highlighted as I believe that's bad practice and messy, but it's up to you to change the respective lines and values to suit your taste for the end result.

Let us know if this helps.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  I appreciate all the help.  Apologize for the confusion earlier, and the fragmented code.  I'd just reached a point with it where I was done messing with it and thought I'd seek some professional help.

Comment: I have one more question BK...in addition to everything else it's doing, what if I wanted to:

1. Take the value in Column A of Sheet 1
2. Compare to Column A of Sheet 2
3. If it exists in Column A of Sheet 2, then highlight the row Red in Column A of Sheet 1.
4. Move to the next row.
5. Repeat until all of the values in Column A sheet 1 were compared with all of the values in Column A of Sheet 2.

Comment: I suggest starting a new question for that and detailing what you need there. I think you already have the ability to paste screenshots so it's much easier. If you can post in within the hour, I can answer it. :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21712902/replace-a-string-in-column-c-based-on-matching-index-in-column-a-part-2

Answer (score 0):

I think you can use this code.
Values not found will be added to the end of destination sheet.
Differences are signed with a blue(change if you want) background color.

```
Sub copy_d()
Dim r1 As Long, rfound, vfound
Dim w1, w2, v, lastR As Long, lastC As Long
Set w1 = Sheets("sheet1") ' change the origin sheet at will
Set w2 = Sheets("sheet2") ' change the destination sheet at will
r1 = 1 ' assuming data start in row 1, change it if not
Do While Not IsEmpty(w1.Cells(r1, 1))
 v = w1.Cells(r1, 1)
 rfound = Application.Match(v, w2.Columns(1), 0) ' look for value
 If Not IsError(rfound) Then ' found it?
  vfound = w2.Cells(rfound, 3)
  If w1.Cells(r1, 3) <> vfound Then ' value in column C is different?
   w2.Cells(rfound, 3) = w1.Cells(r1, 3) ' update based on origin sheet
   lastC = w2.Cells(rfound, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
   w2.Range(w2.Cells(rfound, 1), w2.Cells(rfound, lastC)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
  End If
 Else
  lastR = w2.Cells(1, 1).End(xlDown).Row + 1
  w1.Rows(r1).copy Destination:=w2.Rows(lastR) ' copy to last row of dest sheet
  lastC = w2.Cells(lastR, 1).End(xlToRight).Column
  w2.Range(w2.Cells(lastR, 1), w2.Cells(lastR, lastC)).Interior.ColorIndex = 5
 End If
 r1 = r1 + 1
Loop
End Sub
```